# Android Zxing (barcode library). How to change the after scan intent

Tags: android, zxing

I am developing an Android application, I need to embed the Zxing scanner. The application should allow the user to scan a QR Code and then store the QR code ID of the product and parse it from an XML file. As yet, I have used the simple code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.setPackage(getPackageName());        
intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

What this code does is, scans the product and bring me back to the previous screen of my app. I haven't included the entire library from Zxing as I wanted the Barcode scanner to handle it, but it seems I have to do more than I already have done.

Comment: i don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make an `onActivityResult` method that will get the callback once barcode scanner is done. Inside there you will handle the code string and do whatever you like with it.

```
/*Here is where we come back after the Barcode Scanner is done*/
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // contents contains whatever the code was
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");

            // Format contains the type of code i.e. UPC, EAN, QRCode etc...
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

            // Handle successful scan
            Log.i("TAG",format + "\t" + contents);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel. If the user presses 'back' before a code is scanned.
            Log.i("TAG","Canceled");
        }
    }
}
```

This example just logs the results, you'll need to expand upon it to do whatever you want with the info you get back from the scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Better still, use the `IntentIntegrator` class supplied with the project. It wraps up all the details listed here and its documentation already tells you exactly how to integrate it into your app. It deals with things for you like getting the app installed if not already.